# Why is my Java/Spring/Tomcat stack translating non English characters into two separate characters?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

When I visit the URL http://localhost:8080/myapp/search?q=jalape%C3%B1os&p=1 and use request.getParamter("q") the string becomes jalapeÃ±os instead of jalapeños. Obviously this is a problem.

I'm running Spring 3 with tomcat, everything "says" it's coming through as UTF8; which means it should be rendering as jalapeños.

Help?!

Comment: how about the client's accept-header. Does that include UTF-8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [encoding problem in servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296654/encoding-problem-in-servlet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the tomcat's encoding.
According to the Servlet spec (see http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding) the default one is not UTF-8, but ISO-8859-1

Also take a look at http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q3 . This might well solve your issues.

Comment: So, the answer was a combination of Funtik and Jigar's I modified the Connector and added the useBodyEncodingForURI="true"

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure tomcat something like this

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
 maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
 enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
 connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
 compression="on" 
 compressionMinSize="128" 
 noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
 URIEncoding="UTF-8"
/>
```

**Note: URIEncoding  UTF8**

**Also See**

- [encoding-problem-in-servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296654/encoding-problem-in-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason possible is a UTF8 misconfiguration in your software chain.

Recheck :
- Server configuration for this host
- Spring configuration
- Java Config for the web application
- And of course your meta data in the head of the webpage :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```